# ReferenceError from custom Object in Meteor

Tags: meteor, javascript-objects

My user defined javascript Object throws a ReferenceError even though the JS file which defines the object has been processed.

I'm running Meteor (1.2) and responding to a Server connection.  In my "models" directory I have a JS file that defines:

```
function XElement(name, children) {...};
```

I am using this object extensively in my code without problem, except in one scenario.

In another "models" file, I define an object with the following structure:

```
phraseTypeMap = {
     anchor: {
          editor: function(){...},
          noEditor: function(){...},
          xml: function(){...},
     }
}
```

The phraseTypeMap object has multiple top-level attributes that each have the same sub-attributes (editor, noEditor & xml).  It's a way for me to define the output of one type of data in three different contexts.  I find the appropriate index for my context and pass my properties to the function reference.  For example:

```
var formatter = phraseTypeMap.anchor.xml;
formatter();
```

The 'xml' function calls "new XElement('name', 'child');" and that's when I get the ReferenceError exception.

With both JS files in the models directory, shouldn't the XElement object be defined and in scope?  I even defined a global variable in the same file where I define XElement and I can get the variable's value on the line before the ReferenceError exception gets thrown.  So, why isn't the Object defined?

Comment: Meteor loads files in alphabetical order (within a dir), but if that's it then I don't know why you can access that global var. I can't think of anything else than a typo or the xml fn referencing something else that throws the error. Can you reproduce just this error and share it?

Comment: Thanks @datacarl.  I think I've simplified the error even further.

Comment: My IronRouter server route calls XMLFactory.renderDocument(), which should returns a string with the whole document. This function is defined in "models/xml_factory.js" as "XMLFactory.renderDocument = function () {...}". I've called function testXElement() as the first line of XMLFactory.renderDocument().  It's defined in "models/x1test.js" so this function is defined in a file that comes first alphabetically.  I get the ReferenceError thrown for testXElement().

Comment: Eh wait, are you calling the code on the client or the server, or both? Are you sure it's defined on both the server and the client?

Comment: I'm calling it on the server.  I think that anything in app/models is available to both.  At least, that's been the case so far.

Comment: Yes that's available everywhere. If that's not it I'm out of clues. Sorry.